# error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status CS106B Stanford Qt Creator

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt-creator

I am new to C++ and I have just started the CS106B course of Stanford with their online resources.

I am currently using Ubuntu and when I try to build the sample-project in Qt Creator I get the following issue

```
error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

On my compile output I get the following:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lGL
Makefile:426: recipe for target 'sample-project' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sample-project] Error 1
14:29:38: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project sample-project (kit: Desktop Qt 5.11.1 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Any help is super appreciated

Comment: https://web.stanford.edu/dept/cs_edu/qt-creator/qtcreator/sample-project.zip

The sample-project location is at the above link

Comment: `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lGL` this indicates a problem with your opengl libraries.

Comment: This may help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/96087/how-to-install-opengl-glut-libraries

Answer (score 1):

I've challenged the same problem. Try this:

- open terminal
- input cmd: sudo apt-get install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev
- press 'y'

This solved my problem.

Best regards.